# How to run a program on another computer from c++ code?

Tags: c++, ssh

I would like to have my c++ program on PC1 launch another program on PC2 given the hostname of PC2. I don't really want to overcomplicate things right now, so let's just assume that the program is on the search path for executables on PC2. From what I understand this can be done over ssh somehow? Assuming (to simplify further) I have an account on both PC1 and PC2 so that ssh would just connect me if I'm logged in on PC1 (without any kind of interaction that would require my to supply the username and password) how would I go about doing this? Would https://www.libssh.org/ help simplify things?

Comment: Do you know how you would do it by hand from the CLI? Just put that same command in a `system()` call to execute the shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a command line to execute the remote command using `ssh`. Then execute that command using `system()`.

```
std::string pc2_hostname;
std::string cmd = "ssh " + pc2_hostname + " command_to_execute";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Comment: I see. What would happen if i used this solution but it turns out i do have to supply username/password? Can i somehow check if ssh is trying to interact with the user after the program calls system()? I know i specifically said that won't be needed in the OP so this is kind of a bonus question.

Comment: You should configure password-less SSH. If it does need a password, it will prompt the user.

Comment: Is there a way to have the program print an error if SSH will need a password?

Comment: You can set the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable to the name of a program to use to get the password, instead of prompting the user. You could provide your own program that just prints an error.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested by this C++ RPC library:

http://szelei.me/introducing-rpclib

From their own example, on the remote computer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rpc/server.h"

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo was called!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Creating a server that listens on port 8080
    rpc::server srv(8080);

    // Binding the name "foo" to free function foo.
    // note: the signature is automatically captured
    srv.bind("foo", &foo);

    // Binding a lambda function to the name "add".
    srv.bind("add", [](int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    // Run the server loop.
    srv.run();

    return 0;
}
```

On the local computer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rpc/client.h"

int main() {
    // Creating a client that connects to the localhost on port 8080
    rpc::client client("127.0.0.1", 8080);

    // Calling a function with paramters and converting the result to int
    auto result = client.call("add", 2, 3).as<int>();
    std::cout << "The result is: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To execute absolutely anything, you could have a "system" call on the remote computer. So on the server side have:

```
    // Binding a lambda function to the name "system".
    srv.bind("system", [](char const * command) {
        return system(command);
    });
```

And now on the client side you do:

```
    auto result = client.call("system", "ls").as<int>();
```

Obviously, you need to think about security if you want to use such a library. This would work well on a trusted LAN environment. It may not be such a good idea in a public network like the Internet.